# Hooking Windows text draw APIs

Tags: windows, winapi, hook, easyhook, apimonitor

I am trying to hook all draw text APIs in Windows by hooking TextOut,DrawText,ExtTextOut, BitBlt. However, I see that there is strange thing that it is not consistent between machines. I see the the draw text APIs in some machines by my tool as well as using the API Monitor tool, but in some other machines, I could not see any draw text API called. This is really strange to me since it must call API to draw text except it uses other APIs that I did not hook. 
Does any one know which APIs that I can try to hook? Or why those machines have difference in draw text?

Thanks.

Comment: You are just hooking the old ones.  For just text, you are not hooking  DrawTextEx, Uniscribe, GDI+, DirectWrite and whatever Adobe is doing.

Comment: Why do you need to hook the draw text APIs?  You might want to investigate [mirror drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568315(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Comment: I would like to extract from window on screen. API Hook is an option in the tool only. Can you explain the mirror drivers you meant? This issue is strange to me, since in some machines, I can see the ExtextOutW draws those text, but not in other machines. I use the API Monitor tool to check, but don't see any text draw API called.